# How to dynamically fill key and value in an associative array using for loop in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, dynamic-arrays

```
$main= array(
    "data"=>array(
        "userid"=>"1",
        "$str",
        "acc_id"=>"10",
        "fi"=>"3"
    ),
    "next"=>"4"
);
```

Here i added

```
"value1"=>"$row->field1",
"value2"=>"$row->field2",
"value3"=>"$row->field3",
"value4"=>"$row->field4"
```

using `$str` Dynamically with the help of for loop because it is dynamic not fixed.

I want to make this array like the below, so it can work and print correct output  - It's my desired output(I want this array like this to be working)

```
array(
    "data"=>array(
        "userid"=>"$row->uid",
        "value1"=>"$row->field1",
        "value2"=>"$row->field2",
        "value3"=>"$row->field3",
        "value4"=>"$row->field4",
        "acc_id"=>"$acc_id",
        "tloop"=>"$timeloopc"
    ),
    "next"=>"$next"
);
```

Output is - 
But array taking the value of $str as string and when i print thisit shows output -

```
Array ( 
    [data] => Array ( 
        [user1] => 1 
        [0] => "value1"=>"$row->field1",
        "value2"=>"$row->field2",
        "value3"=>"$row->field3",
        "value4"=>"$row->field4",
        "value5"=>"$row->field5" 
        [user2] => 2 
        [fi] => 3 
    ) 
    [next] => 4 
)
```

The Above output is issue... Here array processing some key and value but not processing $str value... it's taking it as sting.

It's now processing the `$str` values as string from  `"value1"` and `"field1"`..to..`4`

Help me to dynamically fill key and value in an associative array using for loop.

In the array `"value1 and field1"` - here numbers are dynamic - `"value2"` and `"field2"`...

When i am making array dynamic, it's not working like array. If i make it static it works fine.

So please help me to make `$str` value from string to array value(object)...

Here is complete code -

```
<?php 
    $ct = 4;
    $str = '';
    for($cunt=1; $cunt<=$ct; $cunt++)
    {
        $valu= '"value';
        $cuntc = $cunt.'"';
        $rw = '"$row';
        $fild= "field";

        $cp = $valu.$cuntc."=>".$rw."->".$fild.$cuntc;
        $str .= $cp . ',';

    }   
    //trim the , from last value
    $str = rtrim($str, ",");

    $main= array("data"=>array("userid"=>"1","$str","acc_id"=>"10","fi"=>"3"),"next"=>"4");
    print_r($main);
?>
```

Comment: You force it to make string by "$str", may you make a foreach on array2 and do array_push($array1, [$array2Key => $array2Value])?

Comment: You can also use [array_merge()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

Comment: Thanks Bendar.

Actually i tried it many times but i am not getting desired output(Array) that i want... Please help me to solve it.

Comment: I want to put dynamic key and values using for loop in the existing array. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly you want.
There is a code, which build array you'd like to have:

```
$main= array(
    "data"=>array(
        "userid"=>"1",
        "$str",
        "acc_id"=>"10",
        "fi"=>"3"
    ),
    "next"=>"4"
);

$ct = 4;
$subArray = array();
$resultArray = array();

$resultArray['data']['userid'] = '$row->uid';

for($cunt=1; $cunt<=$ct; $cunt++)
{
    $valu= 'value';
    $rw = 'row';
    $fild= "field";
    $resultArray['data'][$valu . $cunt] = '$' . $rw . '->' . $fild .$cunt;
}  
$resultArray['data']['acc_id'] = '$acc_id';
$resultArray['data']['tloop'] = '$timeloopc';
$resultArray['next'] = '$next';

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($resultArray);
echo "</pre>";
```

But if you don't need restricted key ordering, you can use something like this (it's rebuild $main array):

```
    $main= array(
        "data"=>array(
            "userid"=>"1",
            "$str",
            "acc_id"=>"10",
            "fi"=>"3"
        ),
        "next"=>"4"
    );

    $fields = array();
    for($cunt=1; $cunt<=$ct; $cunt++)
    {
        $valu= 'value';
        $rw = 'row';
        $fild= "field";
        $fields[$valu . $cunt] = '$' . $rw . '->' . $fild .$cunt;
    } 


    foreach ($fields as $key => $value) {
        $main['data'][$key] = $value;
    }
```

And there is solution with functions:

```
    function generateFieldArray($keyName, $obj, $field, $rowCount)
    {
        $resultArray = array();
        for($count=1; $count<=$rowCount; $count++)
        {
            $resultArray[$keyName . $count] = '$' . $obj . '->' . $field .$count;
        } 
        return $resultArray;
    }

    function buildMainArray($inputArray, $keyName, $obj, $field, $rowCount)
    {
        $arrayToAdd = generateFieldArray($keyName, $obj, $field, $rowCount);
        foreach ($arrayToAdd as $key => $value) {
            $inputArray['data'][$key] = $value;
        }

        return $inputArray;
    }

    function buildMainArray2($inputArray, $keyName, $obj, $field, $rowCount)
    {
        $resultArray = array();
        $resultArray['data']['userid'] = '$row->uid';
        $arrayToAdd = generateFieldArray($keyName, $obj, $field, $rowCount);
        foreach ($arrayToAdd as $key => $value) {
            $resultArray['data'][$key] = $value;
        }
        $resultArray['data']['acc_id'] = '$acc_id';
        $resultArray['data']['tloop'] = '$timeloopc';
        $resultArray['next'] = '$next';

        return $resultArray;
    }

    $main= array(
        "data"=>array(
            "userid"=>"1",
            "$str",
            "acc_id"=>"10",
            "fi"=>"3"
        ),
        "next"=>"4"
    );

    $result = buildMainArray($main, 'value', 'row', 'field', 4);
    // or
    $result = buildMainArray2($main, 'value', 'row', 'field', 4);
```

Comment: Thanks Bendar for helping me.